# Windows form application c#

Tags: c#, winforms, numbers, addition

I am designing a windows form application in c# visual studio.  for example i have three textboxes Textbox1 texbox2 and textbox3 i want that when user type a number (integer or float) in textbox1 it is automatically added to the values entered in textbox2 when he press enter and displayed in textbox3 .also texbox1 and 2  clears when the numbers are added in textbox3 , how can i do that ?? thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: in your question you say "windows form" but in the the tags you set "wpf". So what is it ? winforms or wpf ?

Comment: What doesn't work in your code?

Comment: By looking at the icon in screenshot, it's winform and not wpf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this(I think you are wrongly tagged wpf):

```
    //please use Property Window to generate this event
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            this.textBox2.Text += this.textBox1.Text;
            this.textBox1.Clear();
        }
    }
```